# How do I alter the css on the solana react module? (with typescript & tailwind)

Tags: solana-program, wallet, react, css

I am creating a web application and am working to add the solana wallet button using @solana/wallet-adapter. I have gotten the button to work but it wont accept custom css. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Wallet adapter components set CSS class names that can be styled.

Not enough details in the question for me to know how you are using TailwindCSS but if it is via CSS file, then here is an example of how to override the button's style:

```
.wallet-adapter-button {
  // your style customisation
}
```